# Showing all possible methods on Jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So I was browsing through YouTube and found that it's possible to show all possible methods. For instance,

[image]

I read you could use TAB or Shift+Tab but I still cannot get it to work. I have the latest Python downloaded. How can I make this option available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first initialize te object. Ex: execute `a=[]` in a cell, then type a.TAB and jupyter will show you all possible methods for a list. (similar for all other objects)

**Example for a list:**

[image]

**Example for a Dataframe:**

[image]